# Update app cache manifest

Tags: html, backbone.js, manifest, offline

I am using html5 Manifest to store an app for offline use, however I want to be able to update the data in the cache when ever the app in online. I have had a good look around and cant find anything decent to help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to modify the manifest file on the server. The browser checks if the manifest file has been modified since the last time it cached all the assets, if it has it will fire an `updateready` event. The browser will then request all the new/modified assets and cache them. The next time the page is loaded, the new assets will get used. You can make the browser use those new assets as soon as it has them by forcing the page to reload:

```
if ('applicationCache' in window) {
  // Check if a new cache is available on page load.
  window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
      if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
        // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
        try { window.applicationCache.swapCache() } catch(err) { }
        // Swap it in and reload the page to get the new hotness.
        var reload = confirm('A new version of this site is available. Load it?');
        if (reload) window.location.reload();
      }
    }, false);
  }, false);
}
```